# How to restrict permission to execute system-wide on Windows

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-11

**Alternative title: How to change the default (system-wide) permission to execute files?**

I installed a new Windows 11 Pro System (not for me) and now I have to protect the system from viruses. I don't want to install any antivirus, instead, I want to do something much more strict. I want to allow the user to execute only specific programs that I specify somehow somewhere, or programs from specific directories. If I would like to execute from another folder, I want to have to change permissions in executable's properties, I don't want safe screens with password prompts and so... Now I have a few ideas and my question is what would be advisable.

The only user right now is an Administrator user called "Admin"

**Now I am thinking is:**
1- maybe creating a new regular user and switching auto-login to login into it
2- change the default permission to execute for the default user (user that gets logged on automatically) on the file-system on the system disk, other disks in the case and all mountable storage media that is to be mounted ever. Then, explicitly allowing the user to execute from a list of directories.

What I don't know is how do I change this default permission to execute?
My guess is to check some options in Group Policy, but I am an amateur for that...

Comment: absolutely impossible.

Comment: What you are describing is called a Mandatory Access Control system, and while there are numerous implementations for Linux, there aren't any for windows, because a MAC would require customization of the kernel.  Windows does support (in fact mandates) what they call Mandatory Integrity Control, but that is primarily about UAC, and not really related to MAC. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control

Comment: @FrankThomas Thank you for providing some educative answer! I will proceed to read it

Answer (score 2):

**What you are trying to achieve is totally and absolutely Possible.** In Windows, you can make things so strict that every single file that wants to run needs to be allowed by 4 types of hashes. But the maintenance is huge if it's your everyday system where you install and update new apps constantly. If it's an ATM or fixed purpose machine, then it's perfect.

I've practiced this a lot and I can put it in 2 categories.

First I suggest taking a look at **my Windows Hardening PowerShell script on GitHub:**
https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security

There are a lot of details about it, and you can find all of that information in that page. It can harden Windows for free, only using Microsoft recommended and supported methods that are official, without any 3rd party stuff.

After reading all the details about it, using it, testing the system, and still not satisfied, I suggest **exploring the 2nd category, which involves Windows Defender Application Control (WDAC)**. Again, lots of information about it, I suggest spending time to get familiar with it and once ready, use the PowerShell module I made called [**WDACConfig**](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDACConfig) to begin your journey. I'll be happy to answer any question regarding any of the things I mentioned here, either on GitHub discussion or comments under this post.

---

## What is Windows Defender Application Control?

Application control is a crucial line of defense for protecting enterprises given today's threat landscape, and it has an inherent advantage over traditional antivirus solutions. Specifically, application control moves away from an application trust model where all applications are assumed trustworthy to one where applications must earn trust in order to run.

Devices where Windows Defender Application control (WDAC) policies are deployed on can either be centrally managed via MDM, Intune etc. or they can be home devices, devices that are private and don't belong to any organization, the computer of someone that you want to keep 100% safe and secure [so that even the device's owner can't willingly or forcefully compromise themselves,](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/How-to-Create-and-Deploy-a-Signed-WDAC-Policy-Windows-Defender-Application-Control) the possibilities are endless.

### Windows Defender Application Control (WDAC) wiki posts

- [Introduction](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/Introduction)
- [**WDACConfig** Module](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDACConfig)
- [WDAC for Lightly managed device](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDAC-for-Lightly-Managed-Devices)
- [WDAC for Fully managed device - Variant 1](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDAC-for-Fully-Managed-Devices)
- [WDAC for Fully managed device - Variant 2](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDAC-for-Fully-Managed-Devices-(2nd-variant))
- [WDAC for Fully managed device - Variant 3](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDAC-policy-for-Fully-managed-device---Variant-3)
- [WDAC for Fully managed device - Variant 4](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDAC-policy-for-Fully-managed-device---Variant-4)
- [WDAC Notes](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDAC-Notes)
- [**How to Create and Deploy a Signed WDAC Policy**](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/How-to-Create-and-Deploy-a-Signed-WDAC-Policy-Windows-Defender-Application-Control)
- [Fast and Automatic Microsoft Recommended Driver Block Rules updates](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/Fast-and-Automatic-Microsoft-Recommended-Driver-Block-Rules-updates)

### [My WDACConfig Module](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDACConfig)

[**WDACConfig**](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDACConfig) is an advanced PowerShell module designed with the aim of automating [Application and File whitelisting in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/windows-defender-application-control) using Windows Defender Application Control. Install it from [PowerShell gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WDACConfig/).

### WDAC usage levels

There are many ways you can utilize WDAC features and here they are sorted by the level of restriction and protection they provide; From top (having the least restriction and protection) to bottom (having the most restriction and protection).

1. Use Microsoft recommended driver block rules.

   - **No user action required**. Starting with Windows 11 2022 update, the vulnerable driver blocklist is enabled by default for all devices, using HVCI or Memory Integrity.
   - [The built-in driver blocklist is updated with each new major release of Windows, typically 1-2 times per year.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/microsoft-recommended-driver-block-rules)
2. Update Microsoft recommended driver block rules **outside of the twice a year schedule.**

   - The drivers block list itself [is updated more frequently](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-itpro-docs/commits/public/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/microsoft-recommended-driver-block-rules.md) than twice a year schedule, [use my WDAC Module to download and apply them regularly and ***automatically***.](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/Fast-and-Automatic-Microsoft-Recommended-Driver-Block-Rules-updates)
3. Use Microsoft recommended block rules PLUS Recommended driver block rules

   - [The WDAC XML policy content is provided here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/microsoft-recommended-block-rules), copy them, create a new XML file and paste the content in it and save it. [Reset its policy ID and convert it to multiple policy format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configci/set-cipolicyidinfo?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-resetpolicyid). [Convert it to `.cip` policy binary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configci/convertfrom-cipolicy) and then [deploy it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/operations/citool-commands). Keep it up to date by regularly repeating this.
4. Create WDAC policy for **Lightly managed devices**

   - [Microsoft's guide: Create a WDAC policy for lightly managed devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/create-wdac-policy-for-lightly-managed-devices)
   - [My guide: WDAC for Lightly Managed Devices](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDAC-for-Lightly-Managed-Devices)
5. Use [Smart App Control](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/what-is-smart-app-control-285ea03d-fa88-4d56-882e-6698afdb7003)

   - It's just a toggle in Windows Security under App & Browser control. It uses a special kind of WDAC policy that provides more protection than a lightly managed workstation but less protection than a fully managed workstation.
   - It uses both of Microsoft's recommended block rules.
6. Create WDAC policy for **Fully managed devices**

   - The following scenarios [provide the highest protection](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/How-to-Create-and-Deploy-a-Signed-WDAC-Policy-Windows-Defender-Application-Control) against any threats from any sources when cryptographically signed and deployed and properly configured.
   - [WDAC for Fully managed device - Variant 1](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDAC-for-Fully-Managed-Devices)
   - [WDAC for Fully managed device - Variant 2](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDAC-for-Fully-Managed-Devices-(2nd-variant))
   - [WDAC for Fully managed device - Variant 3](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDAC-policy-for-Fully-managed-device---Variant-3)
   - [WDAC for Fully managed device - Variant 4](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDAC-policy-for-Fully-managed-device---Variant-4)
   - [Microsoft's guide: Create a WDAC policy for fully managed devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/create-wdac-policy-for-fully-managed-devices)
   - [Microsoft's guide: Create a WDAC policy for fixed-workload devices (reference computer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/create-initial-default-policy)
   - [Microsoft's guide: Use audit events to create WDAC policy rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/audit-windows-defender-application-control-policies)

### Methods we can use to create a WDAC policy

- Using [PowerShell cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configci)
- Using [WDACConfig PowerShell module](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDACConfig)
- Using [WDAC Policy Wizard](https://webapp-wdac-wizard.azurewebsites.net/)

### Plan for Windows Defender Application Control lifecycle policy management

Microsoft provides the [following official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/plan-windows-defender-application-control-management) to understand the decisions you need to make to establish the processes for managing and maintaining Windows Defender Application Control (WDAC) policies. The rest of them are mentioned below at the **Resources** section.

### Resources

*There are a lot more WDAC resources and cmdlets available on Microsoft's websites.*

### Cmdlets

- [New-CIPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configci/new-cipolicy)
- [New-CIPolicyRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configci/new-cipolicyrule)
- [Merge-CIPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configci/merge-cipolicy)
- [Set-RuleOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configci/set-ruleoption)
- [Set-CIPolicyIdInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configci/set-cipolicyidinfo)

### Documents

- [Application Control for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/windows-defender-application-control)
- [Understand Windows Defender Application Control policy design decisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/understand-windows-defender-application-control-policy-design-decisions)
- [Deploying Windows Defender Application Control (WDAC) policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/windows-defender-application-control-deployment-guide)
- [Use multiple Windows Defender Application Control Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/deploy-multiple-windows-defender-application-control-policies)
- [Use audit events to create WDAC policy rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/audit-windows-defender-application-control-policies)
- [Merge Windows Defender Application Control (WDAC) policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/merge-windows-defender-application-control-policies)
- [Understand Windows Defender Application Control (WDAC) policy rules and file rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/select-types-of-rules-to-create#windows-defender-application-control-policy-rules)
- [Testing and Debugging AppId Tagging Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/appidtagging/debugging-operational-guide-appid-tagging-policies)
- [Editing existing base and supplemental WDAC policies with the Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/wdac-wizard-editing-policy)
- [Creating a new Supplemental Policy with the Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/wdac-wizard-create-supplemental-policy)
- [Generate Windows Defender Application Control (WDAC) policies Online](https://schneegans.de/windows/wdac-policy-generator/)
- [Windows Defender Application Control (WDAC) example base policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/example-wdac-base-policies)
- [Configure the Application Identity service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/configure-the-application-identity-service)
- [Microsoft recommended driver block rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/microsoft-recommended-driver-block-rules)
- [Microsoft recommended block rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/microsoft-recommended-block-rules)
- [Create a WDAC policy using a reference computer (for fixed-workload devices)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/create-initial-default-policy)
- [Create a WDAC policy for fully managed devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/create-wdac-policy-for-fully-managed-devices)
- [Create a WDAC policy for lightly managed devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/create-wdac-policy-for-lightly-managed-devices)
- [Guidance on Creating WDAC Deny Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/create-wdac-deny-policy)
- [Hypervisor-protected Code Integrity enablement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-hvci-enablement)

Answer (score 1):

> creating a new regular user

Yes, creating a second "regular" user without administrative permissions is the BEST first step to take towards better security.

> I don't want safe screens with password prompts

User Account Control will *always* prompt you for administrator access. It is absolutely possible to set software to not require administrator permissions to run (keep it in single-user scope). Another ease-of-use option is using a physical key instead of a password for UAC prompts.

---

> I want to allow the user to execute only specific programs that I specify

Windows 10 and Windows 11 include two technologies that can be used for application control, depending on your specific scenarios and requirements. I'll copy/paste their basic descriptions, but they are both essentially application whitelisting:

- [Windows Defender Application Control (WDAC)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/wdac-and-applocker-overview): WDAC was introduced with Windows 10 and allows organizations to control which drivers and applications are allowed to run on their Windows clients.
- [AppLocker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/applocker-overview): AppLocker helps you control which apps and files users can run. These include executable files, scripts, Windows Installer files, dynamic-link libraries (DLLs), packaged apps, and packaged app installers.

Both will let you define what you allow to run through all kinds of rules. Folder path, file hash, author signature, etc.

They are a **lot** of work to configure and manage over time, and not something you set up once on a PC and hand to someone else.

---

Application control is a great addition to technology like antivirus, but it won't stop anything from running as a process you've already allowed. For example, a browser or pdf viewer running malicious code from a website/extension/file/macro, etc.

Comment: Thank you for answering! What I meant by not asking for password is that I want it to say "You can't run this and not even pasword will help you". I defined a finite set of programs to use and that's fine. Now, you say there is a lot of work with these whitelisting software. But, if I never want to use other programs and I want my user to not be able to run anything by default, is it still a lot of work to do? Other user said it's impossible in the comments on my queston. Is it still impossible with these tools you mentioned?

Comment: @donaastor Applocker will do what you're looking for, but remember that if someone has the administrator account, then they can change the settings. The amount of work depends on how specific you make your rules. For example, most software requires regular updates, and these may require changes to your rules.